# How to say "житель Крымска" and not to confuse it with "житель Крыма"?

Tags: toponyms

Here's a title I've found in today's news: "Крымские чиновники получили от 3 до 6 лет колонии".

The thing is that actually the officials mentioned in crime chronicles are from russian city of Krymsk, not from Crimea.

So, the question is - while producing toponymical adjective, can I avoid this disambiguation, can I use something else instead of "крымский"?

Comment: Maybe «Крымскские чиновники»? :) But on a more serious note, I frankly can't think of a proper way to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use phrases like "Чиновники Крымска получили...".

Comment: Unfortunately, it is even more tempting to set the missing quantifier to "all" (instead of the intended "some") in this construct than in the original one. If I were the newspaper editor, I would just say "В Крымске городские чиновники получили...". It is still somewhat more ambiguous than the precise "Несколько чиновников города Крымска" but good enough for a newspaper headline. I have no idea how to get away with a single toponymic adjective though.

Comment: Helas, it looks like this is the only case available. Thank you )